# mysqldump issue

Tags: mysql

I'm learning Mysql and currently covering mysqldump (after I've locked the tables naturally). I'm specifically having trouble with the location of mysldump. The book says, a full path may be needed, which I've tried to do as I figured I'll have to do that as on a local server - much the same as logging in.

It says use...

mysqldump -u username -ppassword databasename; (as an example)

and also offers most locations in Windows with EasyPHP as \program files\EasyPHP 3.0\mysql\bin as I said saying a full path may be needed.

When i log in to the user I gave permissions on I use..

"H:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql" -username -p 
and enter my password.

I've tried this path and failed "H:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql\mysqldump" -u username -ppassword databsename

Can anyone see where in fact I'm going wrong?. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> H:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump -u username -p database

Comment: could you post the output of `dir H:\xampp\mysql\bin\`

Comment: are yo running at the CMD or MySQL prompt?

Comment: mysql prompt with a user I created with all permissions on the DB I'm trying to back up.

Comment: Nah, even as root user I can't get this to work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just curious... are you using the 2009 O'Reilly book "Learning PHP, MySQL, & JavaScript"?  That's what I was using, and its directions were absolutely useless and wrong.  I haven't bothered checking the errata, because there are so many issues with it that I can't imagine how it passed a simple proofread, and trial and error is usually a better guide for learning things like this.

As a newbie, I just figured out this exact same problem after hours of frustration, basically trying to recover from various ways that an easyPHP update to 12.0 broke my development server.

I'm sure you figured this out by now, but for the sake of giving a useful explanation to other users who share this problem/read the same error-ridden book, here's what worked for me, a Windows user:

1. Open the **shell** command line, NOT the MySQL command line.
2. Inside double quotes, list the full path name (from the name of the drive to the .exe).  Because it's in quotes, spaces (such as in Program files (x86) are fine).
3. After closing the quote, -u *username* -p *password database* > *destination.sql*
4. This will export the dump into the directory of the user that logged onto the command line.  For me, the sql file was up in C:\Users\Me
5. In the shell command line again, change mysqldump to the mysql in the directory that you'll be using.  For me, I also modified the pathname of the exe to the updated folder (from "EasyPHP-5.3.9 etc." to "EasyPHP-12.0 etc")
6. Put a -D in front of the database name
7. Flip the direction of the arrow.

Dump command:
     "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe" -u root -p database > database_dump.sql

Restore command:
     "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.0\mysql\bin\mysql.exe" -u root -p -D database < database_dump.sql

Comment: Yes I am using those materials. Excellent answer and no I hadn't sorted it!. That's poor in relation to the materials. No wonder I was off track!. Many thanks for your assistance.